# Non blocking Statements execution in verilog

Tags: verilog, hdl, register-transfer-level

I am new to verilog, can anyone please explain me how does these statements execute.

```
always@(posedge clock) begin
A <= B ^ C;
D <= E & F;
G <= H | J;
K <= G ? ~&{A,D} : ^{A,D}
end
```

As far I can tell, the right side is first executed. Hence, the values for A, D, G, K are first calculated. While calculating value for K, depending on value of G the either first or second expression would execute. Can anyone please explain this operation. Please also tell how the last statement gets synthesized as this entire code is inside a always block and with positive edge clock. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A **nonblocking assignment** evaluates the **RHS** expression at the
>   **beginning of a time step** and **schedules** the **LHS update** to take place **at the end of the time step**.

In Verilog, there is **a well defined event queue as shown below**. For each and **every timestamp, all the regions are evaluated**. If there are any events to be executed in current timestamp, then they are *triggered*. Once all the events of current timestamp are *triggered*, then only simulation time moves forward.

[image: Event regions]

Here, the **RHS of ALL the expressions are evaluated at the beginning of the timestamp** of posedge of clock. Hence, the values of `B^C`, `E&F`,`H|J`,`G ? ~&{A,D} : ^{A,D}` are evaluated and stored internally in the simulator.

Thereafter, the **LHS are updated as the simulation progresses to NBA region** of the same timestamp.

The values of G`,`A`and`D`are not updated in active region. Hence, while calculating the value of`K`, the previous values of`G`,`A`and`D`are taken in the Active region. Then, all the veriables;`G`,`A`,`D`and`K` are updated simulatanously.

I have made an example code over [EDAPlayground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/3rFG). The waveforms might be helpful.

As far as last statement is concerned, I guess it will create a flop with mux (with Select=`G` and Inputs as `nand(A,D)` , `xor(A,D)` ) as input.